The "set" of all topological invariants
I'm not sure if this is stated in standard math texts, my background isn't math, but at the very least a simple google search didn't yield an answer. There are many different properties that are topological invariants: homology and homotopy groups, cardinality, Euler characteristic, etc.
Is it known what all the possible topological invariants are? i.e. has every possible property that is preserved under homeomorphisms been classified? If not, is it known whether they form a set or a proper class? If not, is it known whether the problem is undecidable? A resource recommendation would also be appreciated.

Is what problem undecidable, exactly?

If we restrict ourselves to homeomorphism types of topological spaces below a given cardinality, then we can avoid worrying about proper classes. In that case, we can define all topological properties that are preserved by homeomorphism as follows:
Let $\mathcal H$ denote the homeomorphism types of topological spaces of cardinality below some $\kappa$. For each $\mathcal S \subset H$ there is a topological property $I_\mathcal S$.
$$X \text{ has } I_\mathcal S \iff X \simeq Y \text{ for some } Y \in \mathcal S$$
It can also be seen every "topological property" defines such a set $\mathcal S \subset \mathcal H$ and the property is $I_\mathcal S$.
I don't think you will get a more satisfactory answer than that!

could you define your $S$ and $K$ please?

@KandC Whoops, $K$ should be $\mathcal H$. $\mathcal S $ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathcal H$.

Thanks. Just for my clarity, Is your cardinality $\kappa$ necessarily finite, or it need not be?

@KandC $\kappa$ can be infinite if you like.
